# ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'tkinter.StringVar'>

Tags: python, csv, tkinter, openfiledialog, valueerror

Here is a simplified version of some code that I have. In the first frame, the user selects a csv file using 'tk.filedialog' and it is meant to be plotted on the same frame on the canvas.

There is also a second frame that is capable of plotting the graph in case it is easier to do it across a different frame.

Running this version of the code results in the error: "ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: ". I am not sure how to  get this code to work without this problem occurring, so that the user selected file plots on the empty graph with columns 'a' and 'b'.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("TkAgg")

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg

from matplotlib.figure import Figure


fig = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)

LARGE_FONT= ("Verdana", 12)

class GUI(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "GUI")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Home, Graph):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(Home)




    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class Home(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Start Page", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)



        ftypes = [
                ('CSV files','*.csv')
        ]

        def browsefunc2():
            filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=ftypes)
            pathlabel2.config(text=filename)

            filename = filename.get()
            return filename



        #this line is just used to check that hard-coding in a filename works, which it does providing 'filename = tk.StringVar()' is removed
        #filename = '...'


        filename = tk.StringVar()

        df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='latin-1')

        browsebutton = tk.Button(self, borderwidth=0, text="Browse", command=browsefunc2, height=1, width=10)
        browsebutton.pack()

        pathlabel2 = tk.Label(self, borderwidth=0)
        pathlabel2.pack()

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)


        df.plot.scatter('a', 'b', ax=ax)

        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Graph",
                             command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Graph))
        button2.pack()

class Graph(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Graph", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10,padx=10)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, self)

       #this line causes a problem as the dataframe is not recognised across frames
        df.plot.scatter('a', 'b', ax=ax)

        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Home))
        button3.pack()

app = GUI()
app.mainloop()
```

As far as I'm aware it's not possible to upload a .csv file onto StackOverflow so I have recreated an example one, but the file type needs to be .csv.

```
a,b
1,10
2,32
3,23
4,5
5,4
6,66
7,7
8,19
9,31
10,44
```

Answer (score 4):

I haven't run your 'simplified' version of the code because it's *by no means* a  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

The error tells you that you're assuming something is a path or buffer when it is `StringVar`. I believe the error is on the line:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='latin-1')
```

this requires `filename` to be a path or buffer object where as on the very line above `filename` is indeed a `StringVar` object:

```
filename = tk.StringVar()

df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='latin-1')
```

In order to reach the value of `StringVar` or any of the Variable subclass types, one needs to use `get` method.

```
filename.get()
```

However, that would result an empty string, `''` which would raise another error.

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem with PyQt5. Not sure what was going on, I used `print(filename)` and found that the `string` included the filter information (i.e. `("*.csv")`.

Using:

```py
savePath, _filter = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Some Title", "someFile.csv", "CSV files (*.csv)")
```

the filter info was stripped off and saving worked without error.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem with PyQt5 and opening a file. Found that when in my case using

```
filename = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', '', 'csv(*.csv)')
```

that the file dialog reads in the filename + , 'csv(*.csv)')

To get just the filename from something like QFileDialog or something similar you can grab the first value in that 'filename'

```
file = filename[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happens when you initialize file name inside the constructor and pass it over to a function.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    send_fig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, plot_file=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        .
        .
        .

        self.plot_file = "./filename.csv"
        self.plot(self.plot_file)

    def plot(self, file_name):
        print(file_name)
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8', engine='python')
```

This raises an error:

> raise ValueError(msg.format(_type=type(filepath_or_buffer)))
>   ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: class 'int'

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    send_fig = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, plot_file=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        .
        .
        .

        self.plot(self.plot_file)

    def plot(self, file_name):
        print(file_name)
        # file_name = "./filename.csv"
        df = pd.read_csv(file_name, encoding='utf-8', engine='python')
```

This shoud work fine, either you define file name in the function plot or simply pass it the constructor as:

```
file_name = "./filename.csv"
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
ex = MainWindow(file_name)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```